# Integrate Aweber in Android?

Tags: android, aweber

How to integrate **Aweber in android** ,i research lot but there is no source code for this, so please help and should be appreciated

Comment: What is aweber? I've never even heard of it.

Comment: Please inform us if you get the answar.

Comment: This is email marketing pls see this link [link] https://labs.aweber.com/

Answer (score 0):

AWeber doesn't currently have a ready-made Android client library.  You can approach this in a couple of ways:

One possibility is to implement your own API code.  AWeber's API uses REST-based resources over standard HTTPS, and uses oAuth 1.0a for authentication.  There should be libraries available for Android development that can accomodate your needs - I know that there have been successful "home-rolled" Java, .Net, and other integrations done by third parties so I don't see why Android should be any different.

In this case, I would suggest using the official Python or PHP library as an example of how your code can be implemented. In particular the PHP library has all of the oAuth code out "in plain sight" so it's useful in gaining insight into how authentication works.

Another interesting possibility is to attempt to use the AWeber Python module along with some of the open source projects out there that purport to allow developers to use Python on Android.  I find this possibility personally intriguing but I haven't had the spare time to try it out.

While AWeber doesn't currently offer support for Android itself, the API team has documented the authentication process in some detail here:

https://labs.aweber.com/docs/authentication

That reference may help you out if you decide to go the route of rolling your own library.

If you run into any issues with your library, definitely contact the API Support team at api@aweber.com - while they may not have direct support for Android right now, they can often be of assistance in debugging your own library based on what they see on the server side.